# Discord bot to send a random image from the chosen file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot that randomly chooses an image (images) which is in the same directory (Cats) as the python file(cats.py). This is what my code looks like right now:

```
Cats = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "/images")

@client.command()
async def cat(ctx, **kwargs):
    await ctx.send(choice(Cats))
```

I am not getting any errors. The bot goes online and when I ping it with ~cat it spits out random letters.  I know my issue is with the async (possibly the kwargs) and await line, but cannot pin point exactly what is the issue. I am new to programming bots in Python so there might be a silly mistake that I am overlooking so any lead would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you a subdirectory called images that contains a bunch of cat image files?

Answer (score 0):

If you send it directly by calling `send` right on the channel you are most likely sending the raw text of the file rather than uploading it as an image.

From the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html%23how-do-i-upload-an-image) you should be doing this:

```
Cats = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "/images")

@client.command()
async def cat(ctx, **kwargs):
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(choice(Cats)))
```

Note that `Cats` has to a string, i.e the path to the file.

Comment: `Cats` is guaranteed to be a string (that's what `os.path.join` returns). I'm more interested in what `choice` is!

Comment: I’m assuming random.choice @AdamSmith

Comment: But if that were the case then it would be calling `discord.File` with the argument of a random character from the string `Cats`.

Answer (score 0):

Some items regarding your code.

1. `Cats = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "/images")`, returns just "/images", which probably won't work because the beginning slash "/" indicates an absolute path and your desired directory isn't likely at the root. If you want to use an absolute path you need to use - `Cats = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "images/")` - with a slash after to go before the file name. Of course you could easily just use a relative path of "images/" since images in the same folder as the script.
2. `await ctx.send(choice(Cats))` - "choice(Cats)" is just a string and choice will return a random letter from that string. You need to get the images/pics from the directory to make a selection. You can create a list of images with something like - `cat_list = [Cats + c for c in listdir(Cats)]` (need `from os import listdir, path`)
3. You need to use [File](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.File) to send an image in a message. (need `from discord import File`)
4. Not sure what you're doing with `**kwargs`, so excluded it from this solution.

Try:

```
Cats = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "images/")
# Cats = "images/" - to just use the relative path
cat_list = [Cats + c for c in listdir(Cats)]


@bot.command()
async def cat(ctx):
    await ctx.send(file=File((choice(cat_list))))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up doing it this way:
`# Bot sends an image of a cat when pinged with cat
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def surprise(ctx):
    chosen_image = random.choice(embedlinks.catLinks)

    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff69b4)
    embed.set_image(url=chosen_image)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by: {ctx.author.name}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)`

Created another file called embedlinks.py and threw in all the links there.