# random image sender discord py python 3.8

Tags: discord.py

im new to discord py i want a command that will send a random image from a file and send it but i can get it to work i tried to use [Discord bot to send a random image from the chosen file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61583040/discord-bot-to-send-a-random-image-from-the-chosen-file) one but still could not get it to work so then i tried this but i still no work if anyone can help me plz do

````
#put your images into the image folder
#images that are uploaded will be moved to the sent_images folder so they won't be reposted

import discord,os,random,asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

send_time='12:00' #time is in 24hr format
image_channel_id='ChannelID' #channel ID to send images to, replace with your channel ID
image_types=('.jpg','.png','.gif','.jpeg') #add image types if needed


folders={'Image Folder':'images','Sent Folder':'sent_images'}
for folder in folders.values():
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        os.mkdir(folder)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)

async def send_image():
    for item in os.walk('./{}'.format(folders['Image Folder'])):
        images=list(pic for pic in item[2] if pic.lower().endswith(image_types))
    if len(images) == 0:
        await bot.send_message(image_channel,"Oops! I'm all out of images to send. Notify my owner!")
    else:
        image= random.choice(images)
        await bot.send_file(image_channel,'./{}/{}'.format(folders['Image Folder'],image))
        os.rename('./{}/{}'.format(folders['Image Folder'],image), './{}/{}'.format(folders['Sent Folder'],image))

async def time_check():
    global image_channel
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    image_channel=bot.get_channel(image_channel_id)
    while not bot.is_closed:
        now=datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%H:%M')
        if now == send_time:
            await send_image()
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

bot.loop.create_task(time_check())

bot.run('TOKEN')```
````

Comment: Can you explain a bit better? What does your code do atm? What doesn't work?

Comment: the hole code it give random errors

Comment: but what errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I understood that you have a bunch of folders with a bunch of images in them and you want to make a command that sends a random image.

```py
import os, random

@bot.command()
async def random_image(ctx, category: str = None):
    root_dir = os.listdir('./images')
    # If the user doesn't specify a category send a random image from a random folder
    if category is None:
         # Getting a random directory and file
         dir = random.choice(root_dir)
         image = random.choice(os.listdir(os.path.join(root_dir, dir)))
         path = os.path.join(dir, image)
    
    elif category in root_dir:
        # Getting a random file from the category
        image = random.choice(os.listdir(os.path.join(root_dir, category)))
        path = os.path.join(dir, image)

    else:
        await ctx.send("Couldn't find that category")
        return
    
    # Sending the image in an embed
    file = discord.File(path)
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title=category.title(), colour=discord.Colour.greyple())
    embed.set_image(url=f'attachments://{image}')
    
    await ctx.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

`{prefix}random_image` ← will send a random image from a random dir

`{prefix}random_image dog` ← will send a random image from `./images/dog` dir

Let me know if that's what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def random_image(ctx):
  Images = ['./Folder/Image_Name.png',
          './Folder/Image_Name.png',
          './Folder/Image_Name.png',
          './Folder/Image_Name.png',
          './Folder/Image_Name.png',
          './Folder/Image_Name.png',
          './Folder/Image_Name.png',
          './Folder/Image_Name.png',
          './Folder/Image_Name.png']
  await ctx.send(file=discord.File(f'{random.choice(Images)}'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).